# Historical romance manhwa with a strong red haired female lead and a younger white haired boy

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a historical romance manhwa that I once read in which the female lead is older, has red hair and fights with swords. She is from a noble family and has to protect a white haired boy from the royal family. The boy suffered a great deal in the past and the female lead was the first one to treat him kindly, which makes him develop feelings for her. For some reason, the female character has to leave for a few years and when she returns, the boy has become an adult and proposes to her.

Comment: Did this story contain any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: Possibly: Seduce the Villain's Father aka Flirting with the Villain's Dad aka Villains Are Destined to Die?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly *[The Flower of Veneration](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-flower-of-veneration)*.

> Cecylia Saryan, liege to the order of Hearthtread and heir to the Dukedom after her father's sudden death, discovers a young boy hidden in his legacy — the Crown Prince Ethan, thought to have drowned 5 years ago. Will Cecylia be able to keep her House intact while helping Ethan reclaim his throne?

[image]

The cover image shows the two leads. The female lead is a redhead; she's described as a knight and the head of an order of knights. I didn't see her actually wield a sword in the chapters I checked. The male lead is blonde, not white-haired, but that's pretty close.

The male lead is the disappeared crown prince, believed to be dead after drowning. This is why she needs to protect him from the royal family; his uncle is the new king after the previous king dies, and the male lead's claim to the throne is better.

Although the protagonist's father saved the crown prince and hid him from the new king, he did not treat him well, and basically locked him up in the stables, out of view. The protagonist is the first person to be kind to him.

[image]

I believe there's a timeskip, as he looks noticeably older in the cover image, but I wasn't able to find the exact chapter or the details around it.

This is on topic; magic does not appear to play a major role in the story, both it does exist, and both leads are described as having magical powers.